# MongoDB Grails plugin ObjectId V.S. String id

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, mongodb-java

I have a question about MongoDB id for grails. I used String id in domain class, it would create string id in domain class which is fine. But when I insert entries in mongodb mannually(run db.Things.insert()), it would create an ObjectId(which is not String) for the new entry, I wonder how we could resolve this issues.

thanks!

Comment: Wait your title says objectid vs string id but your question says how to prevent mongodb from inserting objectid by default, which is it?

Comment: My bad, my question is how to make the data insert consistent between grails generation and mongodb level generation. Due to the two different id types(String and ObjectId), it might be a problem when we search for entries, thats what I want to ask: How can I resolve the inconsistency for Grails level and mongoDb level?

Comment: The only way really is to demand MongoDB console to enter it the same way as your grails plugin does. Hmmm, you could make a wrapper to the insert function which will always define the `_id` on insert as being a string. That's the thing you just have to add an extra field to the document on insert of `_id` and the MongoDB console will insert your `_id` instead of its own.

Comment: Thanks sammaye, I think I solve the problem by specifying the _id as "String" when I insert a new record, like the code I show below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Refrence from: [Mongo Collections - Reference Documentation](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/3.%20Mapping%20Domain%20Classes%20to%20Mongo%20Collections.html)

> By default in GORM entities are supplied with an integer-based
>   identifier. So for example  the following entity: class Person {} Has
>   a property called id of type java.lang.Long. In this case GORM for
>   Mongo will generate a sequence based identifier using the technique
>   described in the Mongo documentation on Atomic operations.
>
> However, sequence based integer identifiers are not ideal for
>   environments that require sharding (one of the nicer features of
>   Mongo). Hence it is generally advised to use either String based ids:
>
> class Person {
>       String id } Or a native BSON ObjectId:
>
> import org.bson.types.ObjectId class Person {
>       ObjectId id }
>
> BSON ObjectId instances are generated in a similar fashion to UUIDs.

So you should replace your domain class's id using org.bson.types.ObjectId

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I could create a new ObjectId first then when I insert it into the mongoDb, I pass the ObjectId.str for the "_id" property, then problem resolved, both mongo db level and grails level will have String type for id field.

Code snippet is as following for mongo javascript script:

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("dbName");

db.user.find().forEach( function(userDoc) {

    // Create a new object Id
    objectId = new ObjectId();

    db.userRole.insert({
        _id: objectId.str,  // Before we insert, convert it as a String
        role: "51437d742cd1d9e80a3f0644",
        user: userDoc._id
    });

});
```